# WSO2 - How to write a response from a DSS to a XML file

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I downloaded and installed wso2 esb and wso2 dss on my pc windows. Wso2 dss has been installed as part of wso2esb. the process I must realize is as follows:
-weep a set of rows from a db oracle
- Write on the resultset and write each line of the resultset into an xml file that I have a defined buffer;
for the first point i used wso2 dss now i want to create a wso2 esb proxy services calling the operation created with dss and insert the data in the xml file.
Can you tell me if there is an example on this? I attach my xml template file, can you suggest me how to insert the data read from the batabase into this file?

Thanks so much.

```
en<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Z1BP_ALM_ORDER_HEADERS_I SEGMENT="1">
        <ORDERID>T0343FS15</ORDERID>
        <ORDER_TYPE>YT11</ORDER_TYPE>
        <PLANPLANT>2310</PLANPLANT>
        <MN_WK_CTR>
            <![CDATA[MAN_EST]]>
        </MN_WK_CTR>
        <PLANT>2310</PLANT>
        <PMACTTYPE>50</PMACTTYPE>
        <FUNCT_LOC>2310-000-202-001-04</FUNCT_LOC>
        <EQUIPMENT>000000000010000002</EQUIPMENT>
        <MAINTPLANT>2310</MAINTPLANT>
        <LOCATION>1</LOCATION>
        <START_DATE>20170523</START_DATE>
        <FINISH_DATE>20170524</FINISH_DATE>
        <PRIORITY>A</PRIORITY>
        <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
        <SHORT_TEXT>TEST IDOC 1</SHORT_TEXT>
        <Z1BP_ALM_ORDER_HEADERS_I1 SEGMENT="1"/>
    </Z1BP_ALM_ORDER_HEADERS_I>
    <Z1BP_ALM_ORDER_PARTN_MUL SEGMENT="1">
        <ORDERID>T0343FS15</ORDERID>
        <PARTN_ROLE>VW</PARTN_ROLE>
        <PARTNER>00000003</PARTNER>
    </Z1BP_ALM_ORDER_PARTN_MUL>
    <Z1BP_ALM_ORDER_PARTN_MUL_UP SEGMENT="1"/>
    <Z1BP_ALM_ORDER_OPERATION SEGMENT="1">
        <ACTIVITY>0010</ACTIVITY>
        <CONTROL_KEY>PM01</CONTROL_KEY>
        <Z1BP_ALM_ORDER_OPERATION1 SEGMENT="1"/>
    </Z1BP_ALM_ORDER_OPERATION>
    <Z1BP_ALM_ORDER_OPERATION_UP SEGMENT="1"/>
    <Z1BP_ALM_ORDER_COMPONENT SEGMENT="1">
        <MATERIAL>
            <![CDATA[MAT_NO_LIST]]>
        </MATERIAL>
        <PLANT>2310</PLANT>
        <ITEM_CAT>N</ITEM_CAT>
        <ACTIVITY>0010</ACTIVITY>
        <PRICE>300</PRICE>
        <PRICE_UNIT>1</PRICE_UNIT>
        <REQUIREMENT_QUANTITY>1</REQUIREMENT_QUANTITY>
        <REQUIREMENT_QUANTITY_UNIT>ST</REQUIREMENT_QUANTITY_UNIT>
       <REQUIREMENT_QUANTITY_UNIT_ISO>PCE</REQUIREMENT_QUANTITY_UNIT_ISO>
    </Z1BP_ALM_ORDER_COMPONENT>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the response to a property inside the synapse configuration and use [file connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector#WorkingwiththeFileConnector-create)r to write a content of that property to a file